# TV movie or episode, a man locks his wife outside during a pandemic

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched this (sorry for being vague) between 2 and 8 years ago on UK TV. It was either a TV movie or an episode of a Twilight Zone/Outer Limits style series

It was American, set I think in a small town. Some kind of deadly virus or plague was happening and everyone was trying to self-isolate with their families.

A man and his wife barricade their house and put long sheets of plastic over windows and around doors including their front porch.

For some reason his wife slips away somewhere but when she returns he won't open the door.
Cue lots of arguing while she cowers in the sheeted off porch.

Memory failure after that, I want to say he gets his come uppance by the end but I'm really not sure

Comment: i am pretty sure i have seen every Zone and Outer Limits (many times) and this plot does not ring a bell.

Comment: @DannyMcG  why do you write: "I want to say he gets his come uppance by the end"?  Why do you want something bad to happen to some who behaves rationally during a crisis?

Comment: I wasn't sure if he got his come uppance, faint memory only of him being somewhat nasty in his remarks to her. That's how come I phrased it like that.

Comment: Truthfully, he did act in the right way, although some might see such a decision as callous when it's not certain who's infected. I'm reminded of a Facebook meme going around along the lines of "I'm trying really hard at this Social Distancing thing, but my wife gets managing to get back in the house." :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be the 2006 film, *[Right At Your Door](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458367/)*.

[image: Movie poster for *Right at Your Door*]

> After Lexi leaves home to visit Central LA, there's a terrorist attack involving chemical bombs. After the attack, her musician husband, Brad, fails to find her and reluctantly seals himself inside his house. He will have to deal with this decision in the days to come.

I recognized the plot from your description. He's already sealed up the house by the time she arrives, and indeed, she shelters on the porch. And yes, he gets his comeuppance, as described in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_at_Your_Door).

> The next couple of hours are spent with Brad and Lexi on their respective sides of the door, who talk about what they will do assuming they survive. Brad imagines that after this they will both probably end up on one of those morning talk shows where everyone goes to reveal their woes. Suddenly, soldiers appear and grab Lexi, and prevent Brad from coming outside. One soldier manages to calm Brad down and explains to him that because he did such a good job sealing up the house, there is no new air to circulate through, but also explains that, unfortunately, when Lexi broke the door window, the virus was brought inside and has now multiplied to lethal levels, making the air inside extremely dangerous. Brad doesn't understand what the soldier is saying and insists that they bring his wife back. A large heavy piece of plywood is put over the back door, completely covering it. A hole is drilled through the wood and a pipe appears through which a gas starts to be pumped in. More boards seal the windows and doors but Brad manages to break down the plywood covering his front door, only to discover that a fumigation tent has been erected over the whole house. He tries to tear through the tent and is knocked unconscious by a soldier, as Lexi screams Brad's name. The camera cuts to Brad as he takes his last few breaths.

### Trailer